# Как добавить один из дочерних дивов в исключение свойства zoom: которое стоит на родительском диве?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

```
<div class="block-parent">
   <p>Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text</p>

   <div class="block-children">
   <p>Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text</p>
   </div>

   <p>Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text</p>
</div>
```

Как добавить в исключение .block-children?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать изменить масштаб дочернего элемента. Для родителя задать увеличивающий масштаб, а для дочернего элемента уменьшающий, пример:

```css
.block-parent {
  zoom: 2;
}

.block-children {
  zoom: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-parent">
  <p>Some text</p>

  <div class="block-children">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>

  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

- `zoom: 2` - увеличили масштаб в два раза
- `zoom: .5` - изменили в 0.5 раза, то есть в два раза уменьшили

В исключение, думаю, добавить нельзя. Ссылка: [zoom](http://htmlbook.ru/css/zoom)

Comment: Не подскажите на сколько мне нужно увеличить дочерний элемент если родительский имеет     zoom: 0.655814;
я имею ввиду как мне высчитать?

Comment: @user258149 - воспользуйтесь ответом *goodmice* через переменные и вычисляемое значение. А вообще, если у зума значение меньше единицы - это уменьшение

Answer (score 2):

Можете воспользоваться переменными css

```
:root{
    --zoom: 2;
}

#parent{
    zoom: var(--zoom);
}

#child{
    zoom: calc(1 / var(--zoom));
}
```

Comment: А если у меня наоборот, там где значение 2 у меня 0.5
Как в таком случаи высчитать?

Comment: @user258149 ничего не изменится: 1/0.5 = 2, соответственно 2х кратный зум от 0.5 равен 1